# How to make a horizontal div rack in css/html?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, divider

So I saw on stackoverflow that you needed to use `float: left` to make divs stack horizontally, but I don't want the parent div (ie. the rack container) to be inline as well, [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epN6t.png)

Here is the jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b41g5omh/
So the text is supposed to be below the "crystal rack" div, since the div is not supposed to be inline, only the divs inside (the "crystal container" divs) are supposed to be inline

Comment: Just so you know, `float` still has many use cases, but it's not the easiest or the more modern way to handle layout.

Comment: There are many better ways to do this, but if using floats, just add this: `#crystal-rack{overflow: hidden;`}`.

Comment: I should add that this is called "clearing floats", and using the overflow property is an age-old solution for stopping floats hanging out of their containers.

Comment: @ralph.m do you know anything better than float?

Comment: I would mostly be using Grid or Flex for layouts like this. Which to use depends on how you want the layout to adapt to various screen sized, but I'd probably go for Grid here.